# Trouble pulling events between 2 dates in Codeigniter / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, activerecord

I have created an events calendar with codeigniters calendar class which you can view here: [Events Calendar](http://www.findtheguides.com/events/category/3)

I have it set up where the events are showing up on the calendar and when you click "view events" on a particular day, all the events with that start date pull up and are shown in a modal window.

Well... the problem is that unless its the START DATE of a particular event, the modal window details don't pull up. I know this is because i'm saying in my query to pull events where the start date equals a certain date...

I'm kind of stumped on how to modify this to say, "pull all records where this day is ANYWHERE BETWEEN the start and end date of the event.

Do I need to run a while loop or something and loop through each day of the month? Any ideas on an easier way to do this are appreciated.

the start and end dates are set up as 'Y-m-d H:i:s' in the database and the $query_date variable being passed in is 'Y-m-d', which i change to the same format in the first few lines of the function.

```
function get_list_events($query_date) {

        $start_date_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($query_date.' 00:00:00'));
        $start_date_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($query_date.' 23:59:59'));

        $this->db->where('active', 1);
        $this->db->where("start_date BETWEEN '$start_date_start%' AND '$start_date_end%'", NULL, FALSE);
        $query = $this->db->get('events');

        $data = array();

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'title' => $row->title,
            'description' => $row->description,
            'cost' => $row->cost,
            'image' => $row->image,
            'start_date' => $row->start_date,
            'end_date' => $row->end_date,
            'venue' => $row->venue,
            'venue_address' => $row->venue_address,
            'venue_city' => $row->venue_city,
            'venue_state' => $row->venue_state,
            'venue_zipcode' => $row->venue_zipcode,
            'contact_name' => $row->contact_name,
            'contact_email' => $row->contact_email,
            'contact_phone' => $row->contact_phone,
            'contact_website' => $row->contact_website,
            'create_date' => $row->create_date,
            'active' => $row->active,
        );
        }
        return $data;

    }
```

Comment: why u have % after the dates in where clause ?

Comment: Wildcard style `%` doesn't do anything wild unless it's on the right hand side of a `LIKE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `start_date` column has the `DATETIME` or the `TIMESTAMP` data type. If that isn't true, please update your question.

There's a common trap in date-range processing in all kinds of SQL, due to the fact that when you compare a pure `DATE` with a `DATETIME`, they hardly ever come out equal.  That's because, for example, DATE('2011-07-1') means the same thing as `2011-07-01 00:00:00`.

So you need

```
      start_date >= '$start_date_start'
  AND start_date <  '$start_date_end' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

instead of what you have, which is

```
start_date BETWEEN '$start_date_start%' AND '$start_date_end%' /*wrong!*/
```

The second clause with the `< ... + INTERVAL 1 DAY` picks up all possible times on the last day of your interval.

*Edit* Now that you've disclosed that you have two `DATETIME` columns, called `start_date` and `end_date`, it sounds like you're looking for items which start on or before a specific date, and end on or after that same date.  Try something like this:

```
 WHERE DATE(start_date) <= DATE('$specific_date')
   AND DATE(end_date) >= DATE('$specific_date')
```

The trick on queries like this is to spend the majority of your time thinking through and specifying the results you want. If you do this, the SQL is often perfectly obvious.

Comment: I have updated my query and i'm still experiencing the same problem. Its because i'm only saying pull all where START_DATE is between start and end. My database has 2 fields, start_date and end_date, so I need the query to say, "pull all events where $query_date is BETWEEN $start_date and $end_date", but i'm not sure how to write it, plus theres the issue you mentioned which I agree with and it further complicates the query.

Comment: See my edit. I think I've addressed your new question.